# How to write a loop that runs until a condition is satisfied

Tags: r

I have written the following loop in R. I want the loop to keep running until there is a case where Y is greater than or equal to 3. I then want to display T which is the number of experiments run until this outcome occurs for the first time.

```
T=0
while(Y<3)
{
  X=rbinom(1,5,0.5)
  Y=rbinom(1,X,0.5)
  Outcome=Y
  T=T+1
}
T
```

I am very new to R and I'm unsure how to change what i've done to achieve what I need.

Comment: you probably meant `while(T < 3)` ?

Comment: from a logical (not syntactical) standpoint, X and Y never change within your loop... thus if Y starts out lower than 3, the loop will run forever... should Y be based on T?

Comment: Here T is defined to be the number of runs of this experiment until an outcome Y>=3 is achieved. I thought it should be while(Y<3) so that the loop only runs when Y<3 then I want to sum the number of times it was run before this happened which will give me the value of T.

Comment: I have previously written a code to run my experiment 10000 times and store the values of Y in a vector Ysample

    Ysample=c()
    for(i in 1:10000)
    {
    X=rbinom(1,5,0.5)
    Y=rbinom(1,X,0.5)
    Outcome=c(Y)
    Ysample[i]=Outcome
    }
I tried this for i=1:10 to check and it seemed to work.
I now just want to run the experiment until a value of Y is found greater than or equal to 3 and I want to know how many times it was run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a do until construction:

```
while(TRUE){
  # Do things
  if(Y >= 3) break()
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the loop ran only when the condition after the while was satisfied. So if i want it to stop when a value of Y greater than or equal to 3 is found, surely the while should be while(Y<3)?

Comment: I see.  Change the loop to a do while loop.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop for this. The following uses R's vectorization and is much more efficient.

```
set.seed(42) #for reproducibility
n <- 1e4 #increase n and rerun if condition is never satisfied
X=rbinom(n,5,0.5) 
Y=rbinom(n,X,0.5)

#has condition been satisfied?
any(Y>3)
#TRUE

#first value that satisfies the condition
which.max(Y>3)
#[1] 141
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many times you are to perform the loop, **while** loop is used in that case. It performs the looping until your desired condition is satisfied. You can try the following codes.

```
T=0 #Index variable
Y=2 #Initial value that starts the while looping
```

At first **while** loop inspect this initial Y=2, if it satisfies the condition then the lopping starts until the condition gets dissatisfied.

```
while(Y<3) #Initialization of your looping
{
  X=rbinom(1,5,0.5)
  Y=rbinom(1,X,0.5)
  T=T+1
}
T
```

Comment: This works as opposed to the original code because in the original code Y was only defined in the loop, not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the while checks its condition it does not find Y. Try to initialize Y to something less than 3.

```
Y <- 0
```